# Sencha Touch String Traversal

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am working on a music notation app using the sencha touch framework with Ext. I have a numerator field of type 'auto' which could be an int or a string. I have a function to return the value of the numerator, which is trivial if it's an int, but harder if its a string. The string would be of the form:

```
'2+3+2'
```

So how can I traverse this to get the numbers out? I've been trying to parseInt(() function, but its not proving useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about standard javascript functions? Your current format can be parsed using function **split**:

```
var str = '2+3+2';
var numbers = str.split('+');
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(numbers[i]);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/triclozan/WpWyC/)

Note that you can use regular expression as the split's argument. It would be useful if your numbers may be separated by different symbols.

Comment: Yup! Forgot I asked this, but this is exactly what I did!